# How to pass parameters to the cloud function of firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using Android.

After the user logs in to firebase, how can I retrieve the user information in the firestore according to the account?

My function is in the cloud function of firebase.
My code as follows:

```
mFunctions.getHttpsCallable("getInfo").call()
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, Object>() {
                @Override
                public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {

                    Log.d("-----TEST-----", "BEGIN000");
                    Object result =  task.getResult().getData();
                    Log.d("-----TEST-----", "SUCCESS");
                    self_tel.setText((Integer) result);
                    return (String) result;
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Object> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Exception e = task.getException();
                if (e instanceof FirebaseFunctionsException) {
                    FirebaseFunctionsException ffe = (FirebaseFunctionsException) e;
                    FirebaseFunctionsException.Code code = ffe.getCode();
                    Object details = ffe.getDetails();
                }

                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                Log.w("test", "addMessage:onFailure", e);
                //showSnackbar("An error occurred.");
                return;
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
            String result = (String) task.getResult();
            Log.d("-----TEST-----", "SUCCESS1");

        }
    });
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: mFunctions.getHttpsCallable("getInfo").call()
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                        Log.d("-----TEST-----", "BEGIN000");
                        Object result =  task.getResult().getData();
                        Log.d("-----TEST-----", "SUCCESS");
                        self_tel.setText((Integer) result);
                        return (String) result;
                    }
                })

Comment: not here, update it with the question so that people could help you.

Comment: ok, ths ,it is my first to use stackoverflow. haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want assistance using firebase-firestore you can use the inbuild assistant.
Goto `Tools -> Firebase` and follow the instructions.

You can pass parameters to the firebase function using `HashMap`

```
// Create the arguments to the callable function.
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("text", text);
data.put("push", true);
```

and pass it using `.call(data)`

```
// Create the arguments to the callable function.
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("text", text);
data.put("push", true);

return mFunctions
        .getHttpsCallable("getInfo")
        .call(data)
        .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
            @Override
            public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
                // has failed then getResult() will throw an Exception which will be
                // propagated down.
                String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                return result;
            }
        });
```

For more instructions [Call functions from your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)

Comment: What should i do if I want to pass a parameter to the "getInfo" function of the cloud function?

Comment: Means that call() is used to pass the arguments?

Comment: Ok, but why can't I call getInfo() in the cloud function? He said that the CPU is out of quota. Is the parameter in call() in Json format?

Comment: It's in `hashmap` format. and accessed from the server as json. Follow the instructions on the link to implement your cloud function and the calling function and see if the error still occur.

Comment: Error: quota exceeded (CPU allocation in function invocations : per day, CPU allocation in function invocations : per day); to increase quotas, enable billing in your project at https://console.cloud.google.com/billing?project=meeting-zyw. Function cannot be executed.   log shows:

Comment: I think you have exceeded your free quota. See this link : [Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas)

Comment: But I just called it 9 times today, why is his CPU so big?

Comment: so big? what do you mean by that?

Comment: A function in the cloud function occupies 256M of memory, thus causing the CPU to exceed the quota when calling function.

Comment: how to pass multiple parameters to function & how to handle it in js code?