# Firebase functions user().onCreate: Pass parameters

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have 2 types of users, admins and normal users. In my firebase database, each admin has a document in a 'texts' collection. So, when a new user is created, I want to check if it is an admin or not.
On my Flutter client however, I cant pass any other param than email and password, so how does my function know, if the user that is creating an account is an admin or not?

This is my function without the check:

```
exports.onAdminCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
// If user is an admin
try {
    return admin.firestore().collection('texts').doc(user.uid).create({author: user.displayName, text: null});
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return null;
}
// Else
console.log('No admin');
return null;
});
```

Comment: There is no way to pass additional information to the `auth.user().onCreate` function. The typical workaround is to either call a Callable Cloud Function after creating the user from the client, or having that Cloud Function handle the entire user creation and calling it from the client.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ok, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888994/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-cloud-function-of-firebase) other post can be very helpful for you. As you can see there, you can pass parameters to the firebase function using HashMap

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("var1", text);
data.put("var2", text);
```

You can see the complete example in the shared link.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I dont call the method directly from my client, it is triggered automatically when a new user is created, so I would have to pass data into the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method, which does not seem to be possible. I also thought I could call a Http Cloud Function before creating a user and saving the role as a global variable in my cloud function file, but that does not seem to be possible.